# Control another Program with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation

I have some experience with c# and other programming languages, but I am still a rookie so please try not to use to many big words.

I am using 'Visual Studios' for C#, I want to make a program that will open my antivirus or any other program and tell it to run different features/functions within this third party program.

My question is how do i access the library i guess you would call it of functions or in other words how do i manipulate the third party program so i can for example look for a button of a specified string and click on it?

Comment: This is very difficult (virtually impossible), unless the 3rd party program has published an API that can be used to issue it commands.  About the best you can do is some sort of macro program that can manipulate the location of the mouse, issue keyboard commands to the other program, etc.  The best macro programs can also read the screen to locate specific buttons and the like.  However, how to use a macro program no longer really makes this a programming question.

Comment: Don't. You are a beginner, and such things are not really easy in C#. C# has not been designed *specifically* for the tasks you asked for. It is possible to do this in C# (using P/Invoke) in some -perhaps limited- way (depending on the 3rd party program you want to control), but that's not something for a beginner. Rather use scripting/automation tools that are made specifically for such tasks like AutoHotkey, for example.

Comment: Anti-malware authors don't generally think that an api that allows other programs to turn the scan feature off is a feature.  Nobody thinks that anti-anti-malware is a feature, other than malware authors.  Move on to another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Tutorials)

With Autoit you can record macro or program to automate other programs

Comment: i will check this program out. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

if you want to tell a program to run different features/functions, you need to have its API.

Comment: @elgonzo "My question is how do i access the library i guess you would call it of functions or in other words how do i manipulate the third party program"
Click is just an example there

Comment: And then he continued with "...so i can..." which pretty much spells out what he intends to do. Its a classic example of expressing an XY problem, where the OP thinks he needs to somehow mess around in the innards of that program in hope of finding a way to clicking a button with a specific string on it. But yeah, i get now where you aimed at. Sorry for the somewhat snide remark...

Comment: @elgonzo  "I want to make a program that will open my antivirus or any other program and tell it to run different features/functions within this third party program."
he wants to command a program to do something else, i think simulating clicking is the first thing that  has come to his mind

Comment: Okay, well, i guess that is true :-) Time to take a rest, i guess. Probably focused a bit too much on the automation tag :-)

Comment: @elgonzo no problem friend :)

Comment: to summarize a response to all of your reply's/answers. I do not believe that such a task is virtually impossible especially when you gave the answer of possibility, being the use of a macro program. i have tried using macro go lost and then realized that "Macro Maker" is not compatible for windows 10 which is why i was not able to find help on how to use it. getting into the programs API's is the idea i had but did not know how to put in proper words so thinking for mentioning that, i will look more into it and acknowledge the possibility of the impossibility (of that method).

Comment: @Claies in your first reply you mentioned the use of a macro program that sounds like it does what i described i wanted to do in my original post, click specific buttons and other things like that. if you or anyone else could recommend a good macro program , compatible for windows 10 and that has some sort of help guide on how to use it either from the developer or another source that would be very much appreciated. I will also be looking myself. I greatly Appreciate the feedback/reply's for giving me a better perspective on what to look for. Thank You

Comment: another thing is that i would like a ghost macro, i guess you could call it. Something that acts in the background unseen so i can set it on a schedule and theoretically never have to touch it again.